# Add bootstrap popup behavior after AngularJS apply is done

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a timetable in angular JS with 3 years and 4 quarters per year. Users can drag courses into the timetable and need to see a warning in case there are too many courses in the quarter.

I've got something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="year in timetable.years">
<td ng-repeat="quarter in year.quarters" ng-class="{ exceedsMaxCourses : quarter.exceedsMax() }">
</td>
</tr>
```

In case quarter.exceedsMax() is true, the CSS class .exceedsMaxCourses is applied and the quarter lights up. That's all fine, but now I whant to show a twitter bootstrap popup explaining why the quarter lights up.

So what I've got right now is a method that's triggered after the course is dropped, doing something like:

```
    $('.exceedsMax').popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        title: "Max number of courses exceeded",
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: "Max number of courses exceeded",
        container: '.exceedsMax'
    });
    $('.exceedsMax').popover('show');
```

However - this doesn't work very well and I'm pretty sure this is not the right way to go. How can I make this work properly? Directives I hear you say, sure - but can you point me a bit in the right direction?

Comment: Go for Angular-UI-Bootstrap, it implements the directives you want. Go for the [popover](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) probably.

Comment: No it doesn't. My ng-repeats a bunch of TDs, and only for SOME do I want to trigger the popup, depending on the evaluation of some function in the bound model - I don't see that in Angular-UI-Bootstrap

Comment: @spike...wrap cell content in directive that tells template whether or not to add the attributes for angular-ui popup

Comment: You will have to build it from source. See [this line](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L119) in the code for `tooltip`, which is used from `popover`. Specifying `popover-enable="expression"` will do the trick, when this is released.

Comment: Allright - thanks guys - I'll look into these options

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos - yes that's seems very promising. Any idea when v 0.7 will be released?